# Add line break in a rich content field via Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, richtextarea

In a flow I populate a text variable with data that I want to put in a rich content field on a record.  That part is working. I want to add line breaks between the items that I am adding to the rich content field.  I can't figure out how to use flow and add line breaks in a rich content field.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by adding 
 in an assignment.

[image]

Comment: as a service to the community, you should edit your answer and elaborate with code sample/screen shot